# Hiding URLs in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I want hide the values passing through the URLs. Is there any settings in ColdFusion administrator for this?. I know that converting all GET method to POST will resolve the problem. Then what about CFLOCATION tag.

```html
<CFLOCATION url="test.cfm?id=2654&code=59874">
```

how to hide the values in the above url.?

Comment: There is no simple fix using `cflocation`, other ways are to use `javascript` by making an html form and submitting it from there. Or set `url` struct in session and use in the target page. I don't recommend either of those.

Comment: Besides, converting gets to posts don't really hide the parameters, it just makes them less obvious since you can easily see them in the http headers.  Instead you should [**encrypt**](https://cfdocs.org/security-encryption) them.

Answer (score 0):

Certain methods include:

1. Convert the cflocation to a form post. This will hide the parameters in the URL, but as previously stated, the data will still be in the headers.
2. Use an iframe, and send all requests to the iframe. Similar to above, the parameters will be visible to those capable of finding them in a DOM explorer.
3. Encrypt/Decrypt the values on the before and after pages.